# Python 3 re.sub returns unprintable characters instead of string

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to convert dates in dd/mm/yy format to dd/mm/20yy format using re.sub and capture groups.

```
    date = "25/11/20"
    fixed_date = re.sub(r"(\d\d/\d\d/)(\d\d)", r"\120\2", date)
```

However, even though my regex seems to work on regex101.com, Python returns an imprintable character.

```
fixed_date
Out[42]: 'P20'
```

How can I get my string? In this case, it would be "25/11/2020"

Edit: date is actually a string

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add quotes around the variable. I edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```py
fixed_date = re.sub(r"(\d\d\/\d\d\/)(\d\d)", r"\g<1>20\g<2>", date)
```

From [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) docs:

> In string-type repl arguments, in addition to the character escapes and backreferences described above, `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named name, as defined by the `(?P<name>...)` syntax. `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character `'0'`. The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.